# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined, when actually testing for undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app I have state:

```
  const [functions, setfunctions] = useState([{}]);
```

A test for undefined:

```
if (typeof functions[functionCount].url !== "undefined") {
            imgSrc = functions[functionCount].url;
          } else {
            imgSrc = "";
          }
```

And a JSX element that displays the URL if there is one:

```
<img style={{ width: "100%" }} src={imgSrc}></img>
```

How am I still getting this error?

Comment: Because it's not `.url` that's undefined. It's the part before that that's undefined (`functions[functionCount]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the existence of `functions[functionsCount]` first -

```
if (functions[functionCount] && typeof functions[functionCount].url !== "undefined")
```

Comment: I can't tell you how many times over the last year whilst learning javascript I have banged my head against this issue. Finally I know.. :)